# CreateView template not found

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to create a CreateView in Django, but am facing a 'template not found' error (shown below)

[image]

Currently, I have the following code:

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView, DetailView, CreateView, DeleteView
)
from .models import EventPost

class EventPostListView(ListView):
    model = EventPost
    template_name = "event_blog/home.html"
    context_object_name = "event_posts"
    ordering = ['-date_posted']

class EventPostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = EventPost

class EventPostCreateView(CreateView):
    model = EventPost
    fields = ['name', 'location', 'locked', 'description', 'image']
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path("", EventPostListView.as_view(), name="event-blog-home"),
    path("event/<int:pk>/", EventPostDetailView.as_view(), name="post-detail"),
    path("event/new/", EventPostCreateView.as_view(), name="post-create"),
]
```

You can see I have already used a ListView and DetailView which has worked fine. The code from these views also extends 'event_blog/base.html' so I do not expect this to be the issue.

Here is the directory for the files:

[image]

And the HTML code for the template if you needed it:

```
{% extends "event_blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div>
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %} 
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">New Event</legend>
            {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary mt-3 mb-3" type="submit">Post</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Also the model:

```
class EventPost(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    locked = models.BooleanField(default=True, editable=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    attendance = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='event_pics', blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Perhaps the default template name has changed, but I couldn't find any information to state this. I have also tried adding the following line to my view:

```
template_name = "event_blog/eventpost_form.html"
```

However, this also proved unsuccessful. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not good with class based views, but could it just be a typo?  Your template, eventpost_form does not have the html extension (eventpost_form.html).

Comment: LOL, thank you, my eyes are tired I guess

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @raphael in the comments, turns out I was missing the file extension on my template file... ‍♀️

'eventpost_form' should have been 'eventpost_form.html'